# Insertion sort of items in array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In plain English describe the algorithm for an insertion sort of items in an array.

I've also been asked to use diagrams if appropriate but that's a little hard on here I understand.

Comment: This sounds like homework. If it is, just google for the name of the algorithm and learn it. Insertion short is one of the simplest algorithms you can find, and it will help you build your knowledge both on algorithms and the language, if you skip learning this, then you will probably have much more trouble in the future with any other type of algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [PDF presentation which describes insertion sort](http://ugweb.cs.ualberta.ca/~c115/W07/schedule/lectures/lecture10.pdf).

Comment: thanks for the edit....will remember from the next time...:)

Answer (score 0):

With a quick google search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: haha, the guy might actually reply to you something like "thanks but my teacher said we cannot copy/paste from wikipedia, so I need to copy/paste from somewhere esle"

Comment: @DavidM, haha that's nice1 ;)